# How do I clear state on logout

Tags: reactjs, mobx

What is the preferred way to reset state when the user logs out?

I am thinking of both React component state and Mobx stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just a create a method in all of my Mobx stores (usually named `clear`) that resets all of my observable data to its initial state.

The [primary author of Mobx has stated](http://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/814#issuecomment-292176740) there is no native mechanism for "reseting" a Mobx store. mobx-state-tree, however, does include such a mechanism.

Comment: I have implemented this as well. It just seems cumbersome for a task, which might was handled by Mobx.
Hmmm, why the down votes?

Comment: The downvotes are probably for the lack of code snippets. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The primary author of Mobx has stated there is no native mechanism for "reseting" a Mobx store. mobx-state-tree, however, does include such a mechanism. https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/814#issuecomment-292176740

Comment: Thank you, Nathan. If you convert your comment to a question, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @rvange I have updated my original answer to include what I wrote in that comment.